# Using data on an initializer_list

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, initializer-list, pass-by-value

So I'm looking at the [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) function and I see that it has this overload:

```
template <class E>
constexpr const E* data(std::initializer_list<E> il) noexcept;
```

Let's say that I call `foo(data({ 0, 13, 42 }))` with:

```
void foo(const int* param) {
    cout << param[0] << ' ' << param[1] << ' ' << param[2] << endl;
}
```

Am I in fact making a copy of the initializer_list?

Comment: Are you asking if the pass by value mechanics of `data` is making a copy of the `initializer_list`??

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah

Comment: What else would it do?  Passing by value means you make a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are making a copy of the `initializer_list`.

But, you are not making a copy of the "list of integers".

An `initializer_list` is basically a pointer and a length.

Comment: I just looked into [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list): _An object of type std::initializer_list<T> is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type const T._